# valgrind on Android does not listen to vgdb

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

On Android, running valgrind 3.9.0 with `--vgdb=yes` creates a FIFO pipe that should listen to vgdb commands (along with another pipe for the reverse direction and a piece of shared memory). However, a command such as `vgdb instrumentation on` just hangs forever.

- This is tested on an armv7 emulator with Android 4.0.3 (which is reported to work on README.android) and on a Galaxy Note II with Android 4.3.1 based Cyanogenmod
- valgrind is built with `export HWKIND=generic` and `--with-tmpdir=/data/local/Inst`; all other options are according to the `README.android` file
- Both devices were rooted and were running insecure adbd's
- Two valgrind builds were tested, one built with ndk-r6 and one with ndk-r9d. The result is the same on all configurations
- Both devices are able to run valgrind but neither runs listen to vgdb

For reference, the valgrind command and its output are as follows:

```
# ./valgrind -v -v -v --vgdb=yes sleep 1000
==3640== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3640== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3640== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3640== Command: sleep 1000
==3640== 
--3640-- Valgrind options:
--3640--    -v
--3640--    -v
--3640--    -v
--3640--    --vgdb=yes
--3640-- Contents of /proc/version:
--3640--   Linux version 2.6.29-g46b05b2 (vchtchetkine@vc-irv.irv.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #28 Thu Nov 17 06:39:36 PST 2011
--3640-- Arch and hwcaps: ARM, ARMv7-vfp-neon
--3640-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--3640-- Valgrind library directory: /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind
--3640-- TT/TC: VG_(init_tt_tc) (startup of code management)
--3640-- TT/TC: cache: 6 sectors of 27597024 bytes each = 165582144 total
--3640-- TT/TC: table: 6 tables  of 11531696 bytes each = 69190176 total
--3640-- TT/TC: table: 65521 entries each = 393126 total entries max occupancy 255528 (65%)
--3640-- Reading syms from /system/xbin/busybox
--3640--    svma 0x0000008120, avma 0x0000008120
--3640--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--3640--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--3640-- Reading syms from /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/memcheck-arm-linux
--3640--    svma 0x0038000000, avma 0x0038000000
--3640--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--3640-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--3640-- Reading suppressions file: /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==3640== embedded gdbserver: reading from /data/local/Inst/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-3640-by-???-on-???
==3640== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /data/local/Inst/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-3640-by-???-on-???
==3640== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /data/local/Inst/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-3640-by-???-on-???
==3640== 
==3640== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==3640== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==3640== or are doing some strange experiment):
==3640==   /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=3640 ...command...
==3640== 
==3640== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==3640==   /path/to/gdb sleep
==3640== and then give GDB the following command
==3640==   target remote | /data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=3640
==3640== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==3640== 
--3640-- TT/TC: initialise sector 0
```

The vgdb command is (there is no output until it's killed):

```
# ./vgdb instrumentation on
^Csyscall failed: Interrupted system call
error opening /data/local/Inst/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-3640-by-???-on-??? read cmd result from pid
```

**Some notes:**

- On the real device, the HOSTNAME and USER are not ??? but actually are `t0lte` and `root` properly. It probably has nothing to do with this issue.
- I'm sure that FIFO piping works in the aforementioned `/data/local/Inst` directory because the following works:

In a root shell inside `/data/local/Inst`:

```
# mkfifo examplepipe
# echo message > examplepipe
... command exits after the pipe is read in another shell ...
#
```

In another shell:

```
# cat examplepipe
message
```

- I'm also sure that vgdb is finding the valgrind instance because it doesn't report `FIFO not found` error.
- I'm guessing at this point that the reason vgdb hangs is that valgrind does not listen to the pipe for some reason.
- valgrind operation by itself runs as expected. Callgrind outputs are produced etc. But since vgdb doesn't work, instrumentation starting/stopping and therefore on-demand profiling is not possible.

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of vgdb on android.
The  vgdb-invoker-ptrace.c should be ported on android.

See https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338977
for more details